# Get Tags of specific Branch

Tags: git, go, go-git

Using [`go-git`](https://github.com/src-d/go-git) : is there a way to get only (lightweight and annotated) tags of a specific branch ?

As I’m mainly interested in the tags of the master branch, something like `git tag --merged` would be sufficient too.

It doesn’t seem to be possible with the basic go-git methods like `Tags()`...

Comment: ah, your question is specifically about `go-git` ?

Comment: yes exactly, sorry for the misconception ...

Comment: Per https://github.com/src-d/go-git/blob/master/COMPATIBILITY.md - `tag` operations are supported.  Does `git tag --merged <branchname>` not work?

Comment: There is no such thing as "tags of a branch". Tags are just tags: they are just names for some specific commit. The word *branch*, however, is ambiguous: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25068543/what-exactly-do-we-mean-by-branch — and if you mean branch *names*, those are once again just a name for a specific commit, but those names evolve, i.e., change *which* specific commit they mean, over time.

Comment: That said, note that `git tag --merged` means: *for each tag, check to see if the tag identifies a commit that is an ancestor of the current commit; if so, print that tag* so it's just: `for t := range tags { if t.is_ancestor(current) { print t } }`, more or less. (How to map that to go-git, I'm not sure.) Note that Git's own is-ancestor test considers any commit H to be an ancestor of H: it's really a precedes-or-equals operator.

Comment: It looks like you'll want to use the `Tags()` function of a `Repository` instance: https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4#Repository.Tags (BTW note that tags can name a tag object, in which case you must indirect through the tag object, and then ultimately a tag can name a tree or blob object rather than a commit, so make sure your code handles that case.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly a short solution, but the following code achieved the goal by:

1. Read the commit hashes of the entire branch.
2. Read all the tags of the repository.
3. Check and only print the tag of which the hash is in the branch.

Note: Didn't try with annotated tag yet. But it should be close.

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/src-d/go-billy/memfs"
    "gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4"
    "gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4/plumbing"
    "gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4/plumbing/object"
    "gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4/storage/memory"
)

func getBranchHashes(repo *git.Repository, branchName string) (hashes map[plumbing.Hash]bool, err error) {

    // get branch reference name
    branch, err := repo.Branch("master")
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    // get reference of the reference name
    ref, err := repo.Reference(branch.Merge, true)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    // retrieve logs from the branch reference commit
    // (default order is depth first)
    logs, err := repo.Log(&git.LogOptions{
        From: ref.Hash(),
    })
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer logs.Close()

    // a channel to collect all hashes
    chHash := make(chan plumbing.Hash)
    chErr := make(chan error)
    go func() {
        err = logs.ForEach(func(commit *object.Commit) (err error) {
            chHash <- commit.Hash
            return
        })
        if err != nil {
            chErr <- err
        }
        close(chErr)
        close(chHash)
    }()

    // make all hashes into a map
    hashes = make(map[plumbing.Hash]bool)
hashLoop:
    for {
        select {
        case err = <-chErr:
            if err != nil {
                return
            }
            break hashLoop
        case h := <-chHash:
            hashes[h] = true
        }
    }
    return
}

type TagRef struct {
    Hash plumbing.Hash
    Name string
}

func main() {
    // Filesystem abstraction based on memory
    fs := memfs.New()

    // Git objects storer based on memory
    storer := memory.NewStorage()

    // Clones the repository into the worktree (fs) and storer all the .git
    // content into the storer
    repo, err := git.Clone(storer, fs, &git.CloneOptions{
        URL: "https://github.com/yookoala/gofast.git",
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    hashes, err := getBranchHashes(repo, "master")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // get all tags in the repo
    tags, err := repo.Tags()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    tagRefs := make(chan TagRef)
    go func() {
        err = tags.ForEach(func(ref *plumbing.Reference) (err error) {
            if annotedTag, err := repo.TagObject(ref.Hash()); err != plumbing.ErrObjectNotFound {
                if annotedTag.TargetType == plumbing.CommitObject {
                    tagRefs <- TagRef{
                        Hash: annotedTag.Target,
                        Name: ref.Name().Short(),
                    }
                }
                return nil
            }
            tagRefs <- TagRef{
                Hash: ref.Hash(),
                Name: ref.Name().Short(),
            }
            return
        })
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        close(tagRefs)
    }()

    for tagRef := range tagRefs {
        if _, ok := hashes[tagRef.Hash]; ok {
            log.Printf("tag: %s, hash: %s", tagRef.Name, tagRef.Hash)
        }
    }
}
```